# Conflicts between DDL(ALTER..) & DML(SELECT..) Impala operations - Missing tables were not received in 120000ms

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, impala, metastore

When I execute any 2 queries concurrently :

1. ALTER(DROP) table1 ..
2. SELECT * FROM table2 .. / INSERT..

Impala log file:

> **W0929 09:40:11.309067 28378 Frontend.java:917]** Missing tables were not received in 120000ms. Load request will be retried.
>
> **W0929 09:42:11.316686 28378 Frontend.java:917]** Missing tables were not received in 120000ms. Load request will be retried.
>
> **W0929 09:44:11.323714 28378 Frontend.java:917]** Missing tables were not received in 120000ms. Load request will be retried.
>
> **W0929 09:46:11.330497 28378 Frontend.java:917]** Missing tables were not received in 120000ms. Load request will be retried.
>
> **W0929 09:48:11.337724 28378 Frontend.java:917]** Missing tables were not received in 120000ms. Load request will be retried.

**NB:** I use Impala Shell v2.9.0-cdh5.12.0 (03c6ddb) built on Thu Jun 29 04:17:31 PDT 2017

Thanks in advance.